# Adjust the distance between legend icon and text

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there anyway we can increase the distance between legend icon and its text. For e.g, in the following example, I would like to move the legend label "A", "B" a bit far away from the rectangle legend key (refer to the expected  figure)

```
library(ggplot2)


######################
#create simple dataframe for plotting
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, type = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))
xy
#create base plot
p <- ggplot(data = xy)+
  geom_bar(data=xy, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=type), stat="identity")
#plot base plot
p

#legend text
p + theme(legend.text = element_text(colour = 'red', size = 10, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, face = 'bold'))
```

- Expected result:
  [image]

Comment: Add spaces to A and B?

Comment: @Pascal: Thank you for your quick tip. It works perfectly now.